# Finding planes from their points

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, computational-geometry

Given some points $P=\{x_1,\dots,x_m\}$ in a vector space $(Z/2Z)^n$, if $P$ is a union of linear subspaces all of the same dimension $1<d<n$, can we efficiently find these subspaces?

(Any literature on this type of problem?)

Comment: The related problem where you want to cover points in the Euclidean plane by a small number of lines is NP-complete; see for instance https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00454-004-1108-4

Comment: Is $d$ given as part of the instance, or can the solution use any $d\in [2, n-1]$?

Comment: @NealYoung Either way is of interest to me... also if the subspaces are not all of the same dimension but the dimensions are restricted to a  certain interval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quasi-polynomial-time algorithm, which doesn't fully answer the question but may give ideas and shows that the problem is unlikely to be NP-hard. This is for the variant where $d$ is given as part of the input, or the variant where $d$ is not given but must be the same for all subspaces used.

**Theorem 1.** *For some constant $c>0$ there is an $O(n^c m^{c+\log_2 m})$-time algorithm for the problem.*

*Proof.* First consider the problem variant where each input instance specifies $P=\{x_1, \ldots, x_m\}$ and $d$.  For brevity, let *$d$-space* by a synonym for *$d$-dimensional linear subspace.*

1. In the case that $m=0$ (that is, $P$ is empty), the answer is yes (it is the union of zero $d$-spaces).
2. In the case that $1\le m < 2^d$, the answer is no (because each $d$-space contains $2^d$ points).
3. So assume WLOG that $m \ge 2^d$.  Let $S$ contain the $d$-spaces that are subsets of $P$.  If the union of the subspaces in $S$ equals $P$, then the answer is yes (using the sets in $S$).  Otherwise the answer is no (as these subsets do not suffice, but no other subsets can be used).

More specifically, to implement Step 3 in the desired time bound, note that each $d$-space is the span of some $d$ vectors in $P$, so there are at most $\binom m d < m^d \le m^d$ such spaces, and they can be enumerated in time $n^{O(1)} m^d$.  Each has size $2^d \le m$.  Given that $d \le \log_2 m$, it follows that Step 3 can be done in the claimed time bound.

For the variant where $d$ is not given, note that (assuming $P$ is not empty, and using the reasoning in Step 2 above) any solution must have $d\le \log_2 m$, so one can try each $d\le \log_2 m$ using the algorithm above, increasing the running time by an $O(\log m)$ factor.$~~~\Box$

To speed up the algorithm (maybe achieve polynomial time) it might help to solve the following subproblem faster: *given $P$ and $d$, find some $d$-space (if there is one) contained in $P$.*

Comment: Thanks, good idea to just look for bases of the spaces. I'm thinking mostly of the case $m\approx 2^{n-1}$.